# How many times will the difference of two functions intersect the summation of the same two functions?

Tags: functions, polynomials

Given two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$,

$h(x) = f(x)-g(x)$

and

$i(x) = f(x) + g(x)$

can you know how many times $h(x)$ and $i(x)$ will intersect?

I ask this because I noticed that if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are linear, I only observed one point of intersection between $h(x)$ and $i(x)$.

When $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are quadratic, I noticed two points of intersection between $h(x)$ and $i(x)$.

It seems like the number of intersections is related to the power of the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ from which $h(x)$ and $i(x)$ are constructed from but I'm not sure how to prove it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Functions don't intersect; it is their *graphs* that intersect. The graphs intersect when the functions are equal. $h$ and $i$ are equal precisely when $g=0$.

Comment: so if g(x) is a parabola that is vertically shifted above the x axis, then h(x) and i(x) will never intersect...regardless of what f(x) is?

Comment: The reason you see more points of intersection when the degree of $g(x)$ goes up is related to the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra: a polynomial of degree $k$ has $k$ (not necessarily real nor distinct) roots.

Comment: $h(x)$ and $i(x)$ will never intersect, no matter what $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are. Functions don't intersect. Graphs of functions might intersect, but functions don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)+g(x)=f(x)-g(x) \to 2g(x)=0 \to g(x)=0$$

Comment: so if g(x) is a parabola that is vertically shifted above the x axis, then h(x) and i(x) will never intersect...regardless of what f(x) is?

Comment: Yes. Try it if you like.